# AdMob dont display Ads with my code

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

i'm creating app for Android and Using Admob.

But, using the example code of google: (`ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111`)
His works.

And, using my code (`ca-app-pub-1001454554235256/1768839725`)
He don't show any ad.

Comment: phone connected to the network???

Comment: Yes, Wifi......

Comment: sometimes it takes some time to load, if all the settings are proper then it should work...

Comment: I waited a long

Comment: As @AkshayKhale said it can take awhile for the Ad Unit ID to become active. Sometimes as log as a day. While you're waiting recheck your Ad Unit ID.